# Processor, RAM, and disk usage

Tags: mongodb

How can I know the consumption of RAM, processor and disk that MongoDB takes when I'm doing `find` queries, `insert` queries, `update` queries, `bulk` queries, etc.

I though about MongoPerf but it only shows me disk usage, although is awesome cause can create threads, choose an amount of gb, and read or write. But I need to know how much RAM it takes too, and processor

It could be like doing `htop` for MongoDB

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [ps(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) command (I guess you are on Linux).

Programmatically, you could (on Linux) use the `/proc/` file system (which is used by `ps`, `top`, `htop`). For details, read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

To get the pid of your MongoDb process, you could use [pidof(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pidof.1.html) or [pgrep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html). If the pid of `mongod` server is 1234, you should be interested by `/proc/1234/status`.

Notice that (on Linux) a process does not *directly* consume RAM. The (`mongod` server) process has a [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), and the *kernel* manages the RAM (and dispatches it among-st processes). You could be interested by the [resident set size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size) (and you can query it with `ps` or via `/proc/`)

The virtual address space of process of pid 1234 can be queried via `/proc/1234/status` and `/proc/1234/maps` (see also [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html)).

If you are not familiar with `/proc/` play first with it on the command line, for your shell, by running `cat /proc/$$/status` and `cat /proc/$$/maps` and exploring `/proc/$$/`.

On my machine, `sudo cat /proc/$(pidof mongod)/status` gives some interesting output.

Comment: Wonderful, I will check with `cat`, if I just do `/proc/(pid)/status` says permission denied, and I am root, lol :v